# Explicit formula for a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that the matrices $X_1=(0,-1;1,0), X_2=(1,0;0,-1), X_3=(0,1;1,0)$ form a basis for the tangent space $T_eSL_2(R)$ of the the real special linear group $SL_2(R)$at the neutral element $e$. For each $k=1,2,3$  find and explicit formula for the curve  $y_k:R \to SL_2(R)$  given by $y_k:s \to Exp(s.X_k)$.I don't understand question. How can I find that curve? What must I do? Thank you for your suggests and hints.

Comment: Can you define what is $x_k$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question.